# While loop breaks after the first iteration

Tags: shell, while-loop, stdout

This is my script which breaks on `while loop` after the first iteration

```
while IFS='' read -r line
do
cd /root/clair-container-scan
image_name=$(echo $line|cut -d '/' -f2|cut -d ':' -f1)
sh clair-container-scan.sh $line >> /root/clair-container-scan/$image_name.log
done < "$1"
```

The $1 refers to the file which has the below inputs to it.

```
kardasz/mysql:latest
visualops/httpd:latest
```

Most of them refer this to the `STDOUT` problem, so have already tried changing the `>>` redirection to "`>`" , "`&>`" , "`&>>`" but still didn't work.

The command that redirects the output to `.log` file will run for more than a minute. Sometimes it will not even run the first iteration and will simply give an empty output.

Can someone please help me understand what is wrong in the script?

Comment: we would need to see an [mcve] version of your `clair-container-scan.sh`, it's quite possible something is wrong and causing an `exit` there. Good luck.

Comment: I would also recommend doing some debugging on your own. First run your code (all of it) thru https://shellcheck.net . Then if those fixes don't resolve your problem, add `echo "line=$line"` and `echo "image_name=$image_name"` in appropriate places to see what is happening. If that doesn't highlight where the problem is, then add `set -x` before the `while` loop and `set +x` have the while loop. You may need to add the same inside of your `clair-container-scan.sh`. Good luck.

Comment: Will you while loop work as expected when you replace `sh clair-container-scan.sh $line` with `echo "line=${line}."`

Comment: Consider redirecting the standard input of `clair-container-scan.sh` from `/dev/null`.  If it reads standard input, then your main loop won't get a chance.  You could also consider reading from a file descriptor other than standard input with the `read -u N` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by using for loop and read array. The problem is actually with lines the while loop read, it has special characters like "/ :"

```
filename=$1
readarray images < "$filename"
for line in "${images[@]}"
do
echo ""
done
```